# Memory Leak, Unsure if object is managed

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I'm having trouble with a memory leak in C#. I'm seeing the memory usage in process manager increasing 10-20mb (and more) when no new objects should be getting created.

q1) I am under the impression that managed objects will automatically be deleted by the GC. But when I profile the memory usage using dotTrace, there seems to be +10k instances (in the show new / dead differences) of a basic object I wrote. I found the place that it would be leaking if this were c++,

```
public void TriggerEvent(string tEvent)
{
    oVariable tVar = GetVar(tEvent);
    if (tVar != null)
        sVariableParser.TriggerEvent(tVar);
    else
    {            
        tVar = new oVariable("@CXZ_TEMP_VAR", tEvent, 0, this);
        tVar._BlockDependancies = true;
        sVariableParser.TriggerEvent(tVar);
    }
}
```

Where oVariable is defined as

```
class oVariable : IComparable
```

It seems that the GC is not deleting the new'd oVariables, I am wondering do I need to implement oVariable as IDisposable and make a specific system call to make sure the GC collects it? There are also a few other custom objects within oVariable, but I was under the impression that simple objects which don't use anything external (no COM objects etc) should automatically be managed, or am I mistaken and I've been created unmanaged data structures?

q2) Even with dotTrace Memory showing a lot of new oVariables where there should be zero (maybe the GC is lazy), I still have a feeling the memory leak could be coming from the windows forms, specifically DataGridViews. I was wondering if someone could tell me if I need to do any specific memory deallocation function calls after invoking a DGV update/redraw using

```
tGridView.Invoke(new UpdateGridViewCallBack(RedrawGlobalsViewGridView), tGridView);
```

I had assumed the new'd call back would clean up after itself.

Comment: What's the `oVariable` constructor doing? (By the way, you are doing everyone a favor by using upper-case names for types, anything else just creates confusion)

Comment: TName was standard for type names in Delphi and some other languages, but it's very outdated.

Comment: what is `tEvent` and what does the `TriggerEvent` method do?

Comment: @David, I'm not sure where I picked it up, but I've generally prefix my objects with o, statics with s, enums with e, and temporary variables (local to the function) with t, and until recently, members with m. Would that be considered bad form in industry (should I stop before I start applying for jobs)?

Comment: @David Lively: Your naming convention is fine for variable names, but actual *type* names in .NET should be uppercase (such as `Form`, `Button`, `Color` etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the GC isn't under anyone's direct control but the runtime's; it will run only when the runtime thinks it should. That means that objects scheduled for cleanup may persist for seconds or even minutes until the memory conditions indicate a cleanup should be performed.

However, 10,000 dead instances waiting to be cleaned up sounds like a memory leak. Some things to check:

Does oVariable contain or reference an unmanaged or IDisposable object? If so, oVariable should implement IDisposable and perform cleanup, releasing references to objects it does not "own", and/or disposing of objects it does control. There is a pattern you can use to avoid having to call Dispose() explicitly; look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx.

Does oVariable subscribe to any events of other objects? As long as the object with the event is in memory, any oVariable that has added its handler to the event will remain in memory, because the reference to the method will keep the object "alive" as far as GC is concerned. Again, you should create an IDisposable implementation and have the object remove itself from any events it listens to.

Lastly, I noticed in your comment to another post that you maintain hierarchical relationships, both upwards and downwards, to other oVariables. As long as an oVariable is in any of those lists, it's referenced. I would triple-check all code that adds and removes instances from these lists; you're forgetting to remove objects somewhere, so they hang around indefinitely. Again, disposing of an oVariable should involve (1) removing any reference to the variable as a Slave from any/all Master oVariables, (2) removing any reference to the variable as a Master from any/all of the Slaves, and finally (3) clearing the variable's Master and Slave lists. Only once the object is completely "orphaned" in memory will GC destroy it.

Comment: I've noticed something strange in the dotTrace, there seems to be 20k copies of ReaderWriterCount, which I'm guessing is coming from a single ReaderWriterSlim, there should only be 2k~ objects containing single ReaderWriterSlims, having 20k ReaderWriterCounts is a sign of a leak right?

Comment: If you expect 2k instances and find 20k, yes, I'd consider that a sign of a leak. Again, check to make sure that references are released on both sides of any relationship between your ReaderWriter objects and oVariables.

Comment: I wasn't sure how many copies of ReaderWriterCount a single ReaderWriterSlim would contain, though 10 seems a little high.

Answer (score 4):

First, do not call GC.Collect() it will force garbage collection, but has some nasty side effects.  For example, it will push everything that is not ready for garbage collection back a generation and delay it's collection. MS has information [about generations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx) etc

Secondly, GC will only collect objects if there are no references to it.

So let's say your sVariableParser is a member variable that holds a reference to your tVar.  When the GC runs, it's going to see that VariableParser is depending on tVar and not let it go.

Imagine that you have something like this:

```
public class House
{
   public Person Resident1 {get; set;}
}

public class Person
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your code you have

```
House.Resident1 = new Person {name = "John Calvin"};
```

When garbage collection runs, it can't clean up the Person object that is tied to Resident1 until House falls out of scope and is no longer used.

So all that is to say, that GC will clean up your references, but I'm guessing you've got some code holding on to your tVar, and you don't realize it.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that nothing starts to reference that new'd oVariable, but I'll go take a second look. Could there be any issues with using strings? I'm wording if a string is being passed by reference (unbeknown to me) and is preventing the GC from working as I expect. Having two objects with string members being assigned to a string using the '=' operator should make two copies correct?

Comment: if you mean string a = "test"; a += "123" then yes, there will be 2 copies and the version that is "test" will fall away and be GC'd and "test123" will remain.

Answer (score 1):

What does the internal implementation of `oVariable` look like? If you're using any assets that inherit `IDisposable`, you'll need to close them (or use a `using` block) to make sure they're properly disposed.

Comment: The implementation is fairly straight forward (a little too long to paste here though), the only members which are not basic strings / bools etc is private List<oVariable> Slaves = new List<oVariable>();
and private List<oVariable> Masters = new List<oVariable>();, which I don't think would prevent it from being GC'd? is seeing +10k of an object in dotTrace a sign of a memory leak, or could the GC not be collecting for long periods of time (+30min)? And I'm nearly 100% sure nothing starts referring to the newly created oVariable, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Hmmm... `List<>` won't do that. Could you update your post with the rest of the method in question? Also, the GC runs on-demand; that is not the source of your problem.

Comment: Done, there was nothing else in the method, so I thought the new'd object should be GC'd shortly after.